# CiviRule "Delay Then Send Message" does not include contribution data

Tags: civirules, message-templates

Drupal 7.88
CiviCRM 5.41.0
CiviRules 2.41

We have a custom field that is not written to the database in time to be included on the receipts. So my work around is a civirule which sends a Message Template on a delay. This was all working until one of the recent Rules Extension updates. Now it sends the message template but it does not include the data | {contribution.receive_date} | {contribution.id} | {contribution.custom_57} | {contribution.total_amount} from the contribution

If I run the Message Template manually, it includes the data.
On my last test, I made a real contribution. Then I checked the custom table to be sure the data was there. Next I ran the message template manually and it included the data. However, once the delay ended and it sent the message template via Rules, it did not include the contribution data.

Here is a side by side compare of what we get

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding it to the civirules issue list too :-)